# Load .Rda files in Rstudio from Windows File Explorer

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm often navigating my files in Windows File Explorer to find a .Rda file to load into Rstudio. I'd like to be able to simply double-click my .Rda and have it read into Rstudio properly. Instead, when I do this, Rstudio opens and executes code like this:

```
load("C:/Users/usrnm/Documents/mydata.Rda")
```

With the following output:

```
Error in load("C:/Users/usrnnm/Documents/mydata.Rda") : 
  bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
```

I know that the proper way to load these files is:

```
readRDS("C:/Users/usrnm/Documents/mydata.Rda")
```

but I'd like Rstudio to do that by default. Is there anything I can configure to make Rstudio open .Rda files with `readRDS()` by default?
I'm using: Windows 10, R version 4.0.0, Rstudio Version 1.2.5042

Comment: How did you save your `.rda` files? Did you use `save` (counterpart to `load`) or `saveRDS`?

Comment: `saveRDS()` is how I usually do it. What's the difference from `save()`?

Comment: The former saves one object while latter saves many objects or essentially your environment.